# How can get top n of one column depends on another column sort?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following table:

```
year  |  name  | points
-----------------------
2000  | user1  |   46
1995  | user3  |   25
1995  | user1  |   12
2000  | user2  |   24
1995  | user2  |   33
1997  | user4  |   40
2000  | user3  |   52
1997  | user2  |   38
```

I need to query the top 2 users (with most points) from each year.

It should look like this:

```
year  |  name  | points
-----------------------
2000  | user3  |   52
2000  | user1  |   46
1997  | user4  |   40  
1997  | user2  |   38
1995  | user2  |   33
1995  | user3  |   25
```

How can do that in postgres?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by points desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Another fun method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.points in (select t2.points
                   from t t2
                   where t2.year = t.year
                   order by t2.points desc
                   limit 2
                  );
```

Note that this can return more than two rows for a year if there are ties.